# Python regular expression new line

Tags: python, regex

How to identify/ distinguish the `unknown_var` new line within:

```
.\n.\n#unknown_var
```

Based off of this code:

```
"caption": "~Some text~ .\n.\n#unknown_var"

caption = re.findall('"caption": "(.+) .\n.\n#unknown_var', connection)
```

Comment: Is this even valid python? You should indent code blocks so that they're formatted in a readable way, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks . Show your `import` statements like `re` here. Also maybe explain the question a bit, it's not clear to me what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
"caption": "(.+) \.\\n\.\\n#unknown_var"
```

This would work for you.See demo.`\n` would be `\\n` and `.` needs to be escaped though it would still work.

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'"caption": "(.+) \.\\n\.\\n#unknown_var"')
test_str = u"\"caption\": \"~Some text~ .\n.\n#unknown_var\""

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bT4kP8/1